# MVC 3 API custom response body on error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, http-status-codes

I'm trying to write an API with a login method + others. When there is an issue logging in, I would like to return a custom HTTP error code to the client with a custom response body. The problem is that on error the request is getting redirected to the home page.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult ApiLogIn(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var outcome = _authService.LogIn(model);

        if (outcome == LogInOutcome.Success)
        {
            return Json(new { }); // Empty on success
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return Json(new { reason = outcome.ToString() });
        }
    }

    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    return Json(new { }); // Empty or invalid model
}
```

How do I stop it from getting redirected on error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the fact that late in the request lifecycle, the FormsAuth module checks to see if the `Response.StatusCode` is 401, and if so, redirects to the login page.

You can try a different status code (like 403, granted that's not quite appropriate for your scenario). The other option is to delay setting the `Response.StatusCode` to 401 until the `EndRequest` event in your Global.asax.

I solved this by adding a flag into `Context.Items` and checking for the presence of the flag in `EndRequest`:

**Global.asax.cs - Add this method**

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Context.Items["AjaxPermissionDenied"] is bool) // FormsAuth module intercepts 401 response codes and does a redirect to the login page. 
    {
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        Context.Response.StatusDescription = "Permission Denied";
        Context.Response.End();
        return;
    }
}
```

**In your controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult ApiLogIn(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var outcome = _authService.LogIn(model);

        if (outcome == LogInOutcome.Success)
        {
            return Json(new { }); // Empty on success
        }
        else
        {
            Context.Items["AjaxPermissionDenied"] = true;
            return Json(new { reason = outcome.ToString() });
        }
    }

    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    return Json(new { }); // Empty or invalid model
}
```